# Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:14.0.1 in Java 14

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

In my pom.xml I have added a dependency for `BASE64Encoder`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
    <version>${java.version}</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

But it is giving me

> Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:14.0.1.

I am using maven 3.0. How to resolve it?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I had to remove that dependencies from a project recently, and `java.util.Base64`, while not a drop-in replacement, is easy enough to use instead of `com.sun.BASE64Encoder`, which you should not be using in the first place anyway.

Comment: First `classes.jar` does not exist anymore in Java since JDK9 furthermore take a look into https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html (replacement) apart from that I strongly recommend to upgrade your Maven version if you really using Maven 3.0? (its about 10 years old) ??? Furthermore system scope dependency are deprecate sind Maven 3.0...